# Out of memory exception on bulk data load on list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-leaks

I have the below code to load bulk data on my list

```
List<manager> employeeList = new List<manager>();
var employees = //fetching bulk data here
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    List<string> managerlist = new List<string>();
    foreach (var manager in employee.EntityList.Where(x => x.Id == employee.Id))
    {
        managerlist.Add(manager);
    }

    employeeList.manager = managerlist;
}
```

Im getting out of memory exception while processing this. This list contains around 5000 records in total. Anyone can suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: does the exception occur at the _Add_ function?

Comment: Im not getting any error when processing this code. But gradually memory consumption increases and getting this error. This will happen even there are no operations done in the page.

Comment: apparenty, double iteration looks heavy load for 5000 records. because it takes O(n^2) algorithm. I recommends you to use hashing by **Dictionary** data structure. I guess Dictionary<employee id,manager> is one of case you can consider. then you can break down to one single iteration.

Comment: Is the above code correct? E.g. you declared `List<manager> employeeList` and then set `employeeList.manager` - I guess, List<manager> cannot have any property called .manager. In general, 5.000 items should not be a problem - it sounds like you have an incorrect code somewere e.g. an infinite loop.